# How do I get a variable out of a try/catch block?

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to get this right for 2 days and am about ready to throw something .....

I have a JSONArray which I'm processing in a try/catch block but it doesn't seem to pass the variable out at the end.

My code:

```
try{
    //Get the element that holds the results ( JSONArray )
    JSONArray  getresults = json.getJSONArray("results");
    //Loop the Array
    for(int i=0;i < getresults.length();i++){                       
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        JSONObject e = getresults.getJSONObject(i);
        totalpass = e.getJSONObject(i).getString("ftotalpass");                         
    }                              

} catch(JSONException e)        {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());                                       
}
```

I've tried all manor of declaring the variable before, in, after the try/catch block but I just cannot get it to pass to the rest of my code.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are dealing with json,wherever you will declare you have to declare in try catch block

Comment: need to have good java knowledge before start playing with Android

Comment: This question actually is far more interesting when considering the 1.7 java try block

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Hmm...

You can declare it outside. Such as

```
JSONArray results = null;

try {
     results = json.getJSONArray("results");
}...
```

This way you can access it outside, but be sure to use an if to see if it is null.

If you don't put `JSONArray results = null` the compiler will probably whine about the variable not being initialized.

Further explanation:

This happens because of the **scope**. When you declare inside the try, the scope of the variable ends when the try ends. When you declare inside an if, when that if ends, the variable can't be accessed anymore. This is very useful for temporary variables where you only use them for comparison or better code readability, memory reuse, etc. (idk if this is even a word). Anyway, if your variable needs to be accessed everywhere inside a class, it may be better to declare as a field.

I didn't read [this explanation](http://maiaco.com/articles/java/scope.php), but it seems good. Take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring it outside would solve the problem:

```
JSONArray getresults = null;
try{
     //Get the element that holds the results ( JSONArray )
     getresults = json.getJSONArray("results");
     //Loop the Array
     for(int i=0;i < getresults.length();i++){                     
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
         JSONObject e = getresults.getJSONObject(i);
         totalpass = e.getJSONObject(i).getString("ftotalpass");                                
     }                              
} catch(JSONException e)        {
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());                                      
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the way Gabriel described works, but you could run into a `nullPointerException` with that approach.I'd rather do this :

```
JSONArray results = new JSONArray();

try {
     results = json.getJSONArray("results");
}...
```

Comment: This is true, but I say that he should check if the variable is null. I think this is better because if he don't get any result, whatever he wants to do with the variable outside shouldn't be done, after all he got no result.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable outside the block and assign it inside the block:

```
JSONArray  getresults;

try {

    ...
    getresults = ...; // your assignment;
    ...
}                              
catch(JSONException e) {
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data" + e.toString());
    getresults = ...; //maybe some other assignment
}

//use variable
if(getresults ...) {
    ...
}
```